# CircleCastAll не работает при нескольких слоях, как исправить?

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть код, который ищет объекты на сцене. Я использую `CircleCastAll` для их поиска.
Когда я использую только один слой в LayerMask, то всё работает как надо, объекты удается найти в нужном слое (проверял 2 слоя по очереди).
Когда я добавляю в LayerMask 2 слоя, то `CircleCastAll` не находит ничего.
Если например я ищу объекты только в слое 10, то их успешно находит. Если в слоях 10 и 12, то не находит вообще. Например значение маски для этих слоёв: 5120.

Comment: покажи код_____

Comment: Та обычный код, в нём нет ошибок, что-то с самой функцией. Я пробовал через инспектор добавлять слой и убирать, функция работает только при одном слое, при двух уже не находит.

Comment: Обычный код с обычными ошибками, а мы не ванги.

Answer (score 0):

Ок, проверил, CircleCastAll работает при всех слоях.